# Why the progress bar does not load?

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar

The following code runs pretty well in jsfiddle and here in the snippet, but in the html file that I have the js code does not function and `var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(container,` does not operate.

Here is the link to my files: https://github.com/yzdnisr/js_problem

Any suggestions to solve this problem is welcome.

```js
var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(container, {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#FFEA82',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute'
  }
});

bar.animate(1.0); // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

```css
#liner {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/progressbar.js/1.0.1/progressbar.min.js"></script>
<div id="liner">
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well if it works here then there is something wrong with your code. Put it here.

Comment: Please provide YOUR code or at least a link to your implementation...

Comment: [Check your console for errors](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log).

Comment: Please find the files in the following link: https://github.com/yzdnisr/js_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your progress bar UI AFTER the reference to the progressbar.min.js. Preferably at the end of the document.
In your untitled document it is before.